# Display React Bootstrap's Modal when you press a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal:
Display react bootstrap's modal when you press the button 'Open Modal'

Problem:
I do not know how to make it to show bootstrap's modal when I press the button 'Open Modal'
What part am I missing?

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bootstrap-examples-suktpo?

Info:
*I'm newbie in Reactjs

Thank you!

---

index.html

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import DisplayModalContent from './DisplayModalContent';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      openItem: null,
      items: [
        {
          firstName: 'Josef',
          lastName: 'Anderson',
          key: 'josef.anderson',
          startYear: 2021,
          startMonth: 2
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Jim',
          lastName: 'West',
          key: 'jim.west',
          startYear: 2020,
          startMonth: 3
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Joe',
          lastName: 'West',
          key: 'joe.west',
          startYear: 1998,
          startMonth: 10
        }
      ],
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    };
  }

  handleOpenModal = openItem => {
    this.setState({ openItem });
  };

  handleCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ openItem: null });
  };

  handleOpenItemValue = e => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      openItem: { ...this.state.openItem, [name]: value }
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value);
    alert(
      JSON.stringify({
        test: document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value
      })
    );
  };


  render() {
    const { items, openItem } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <table border="1">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th />
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {items.map(item => {
              const { firstName, lastName, key } = item;

              return (
                <tr key={key}>
                  <td>{firstName}</td>
                  <td>{lastName}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button onClick={() => this.handleOpenModal(item)}>
                      Open Modal
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <DisplayModalContent item={openItem} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

DisplayModalContent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

const options = [
  { value: 1, label: 'Jan' },
  { value: 2, label: 'Feb' },
  { value: 3, label: 'Mars' },
  { value: 4, label: 'April' },
  { value: 5, label: 'May' },
  { value: 6, label: 'June' },
  { value: 7, label: 'July' },
  { value: 8, label: 'August' },
  { value: 9, label: 'Sept' },
  { value: 10, label: 'Oct' },
  { value: 11, label: 'Nov' },
  { value: 12, label: 'Dec' }
];

class DisplayModalContent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      openItem: null,
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(s) {
    if (JSON.stringify(this.props) !== JSON.stringify(s)) {
      this.setState({ openItem: this.props.item });
    }
  }

  handleOpenModal = openItem => {
    this.setState({ openItem });
  };

  handleCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ openItem: null });
  };

  handleOpenItemValue = e => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      openItem: { ...this.state.openItem, [name]: value }
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value);
    alert(
      JSON.stringify({
        test: document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value
      })
    );
  };

  hideShowModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: !this.state.isModalOpen });
  };

  render() {
    const { items, openItem } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {openItem !== null && (
          <div isOpen={true}>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.hideShowModal()}>
              Click to hide/show
            </Button>
            <Modal
              show={this.state.isModalOpen}
              onHide={() => this.hideShowModal()}
            >
              <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>This is modal title</Modal.Title>
              </Modal.Header>

              <Modal.Body>
                <p>
                  First Name:
                  <br />
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id="firstName"
                    name="firstName"
                    value={openItem.firstName}
                    onChange={e => this.handleOpenItemValue(e)}
                  />
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id="lastName"
                    name="lastName"
                    value={openItem.lastName}
                    onChange={e => this.handleOpenItemValue(e)}
                  />
                </p>
              </Modal.Body>

              <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary">CLOSE</Button>
                <Button variant="primary">SAVE</Button>
              </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DisplayModalContent;
```

Comment: The [React Bootstrap documentation](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/modal/#modals-live) seems to have a few more examples if that would help. Is the problem that you want a *different* modal depending on the table row?

Comment: Have you tried the sample link that I have provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to use the state in the two components, just define the state in the parent component and pass it as a prop to the child component.

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DisplayModalContent from "./DisplayModalContent";
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const items = [
  {
    firstName: "Josef",
    lastName: "Anderson",
    key: "josef.anderson",
    startYear: 2021,
    startMonth: 2
  },
  {
    firstName: "Jim",
    lastName: "West",
    key: "jim.west",
    startYear: 2020,
    startMonth: 3
  },
  {
    firstName: "Joe",
    lastName: "West",
    key: "joe.west",
    startYear: 1998,
    startMonth: 10
  }
];

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      open: false,
      openItem: null,
      items: [],
      firstName: "",
      lastName: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ items });
  }

  handleOpenModal = (openItem) => {
    this.setState({ openItem, open: true });
  };

  handleCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  handleOpenItemValue = (e) => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      openItem: { ...this.state.openItem, [name]: value }
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = (key) => {
    const { openItem, items } = this.state;

    const updatedItems = items.filter((i) => i.key !== key);
    this.setState({
      open: false,
      items: [...updatedItems, openItem]
    });
    // console.log(document.getElementsByName("startMonth")[0].value);
    // alert(
    //   JSON.stringify({
    //     test: document.getElementsByName("startMonth")[0].value
    //   })
    // );
  };

  render() {
    const { items, openItem, open } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <table border="1">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th />
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {items &&
              items.map((item) => {
                const { firstName, lastName, key } = item;

                return (
                  <tr key={key}>
                    <td>{firstName}</td>
                    <td>{lastName}</td>
                    <td>
                      <button onClick={() => this.handleOpenModal(item)}>
                        Open Modal
                      </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <DisplayModalContent
          item={openItem}
          isOpen={open}
          onClose={this.handleCloseModal}
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          handleOpenItemValue={(e) => this.handleOpenItemValue(e)}
        />
        <br />
        <div> {JSON.stringify(items)} </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**DisplayModalContent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const options = [
  { value: 1, label: "Jan" },
  { value: 2, label: "Feb" },
  { value: 3, label: "Mars" },
  { value: 4, label: "April" },
  { value: 5, label: "May" },
  { value: 6, label: "June" },
  { value: 7, label: "July" },
  { value: 8, label: "August" },
  { value: 9, label: "Sept" },
  { value: 10, label: "Oct" },
  { value: 11, label: "Nov" },
  { value: 12, label: "Dec" }
];

class DisplayModalContent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { item, isOpen, onClose, handleOpenItemValue, onSubmit } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Modal show={isOpen} onHide={onClose}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title>This is modal title</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>

            <Modal.Body>
              <p>
                First Name:
                <br />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="firstName"
                  name="firstName"
                  value={item && item.firstName}
                  onChange={(e) => handleOpenItemValue(e)}
                />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="lastName"
                  name="lastName"
                  value={item && item.lastName}
                  onChange={(e) => handleOpenItemValue(e)}
                />
              </p>
            </Modal.Body>

            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button variant="secondary" onClick={onClose}>
                CLOSE
              </Button>
              <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => onSubmit(item.key)}>
                SAVE
              </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DisplayModalContent;
```

[Live working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-bush-x1xbo?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

I was reviewing your code and I see you're using `this.state.isModalOpen` to show the modal, but in the `DisplayModalContent` component that state is never updated when you're receiving the props from your index. So, the easy fix for that is update `isModalOpen` when you are receiving the props. However, from my experience I would recommend do not use a new state to handle the modal open state in the `DisplayModalContent` component, you can use it directly from the `props`:

```
<DisplayModalContent
  item={openItem}
  isOpen={!!openItem}
  onClose={this.handleCloseModal}
/>
```

and in your `DisplayModalContent` component, you can replace any local state and in order to use the component props:

```
...
<Modal
  show={this.props.isOpen}
  onHide={this.props.onClose}
>
...
```

By doing this your code will be more simple and readable.